# Adding alternative menu item to Browser

Tags: android

I want to add a custom menu item to Browser. I want to launch my activity on click of the custom menu item.
Is it possible to do so.

i could add my custom menu item to contacts and gallery (under share). I want to achieve the same for Browser.
I am unable to match the correct action and mime type.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add a custom menu item to Browser. I want to launch my activity on click of the custom menu item. Is it possible to do so.

No, sorry.

> i could add my custom menu item to contacts and gallery (under share). I want to achieve the same for Browser.

If you want to be part of the Share menu item in the browser, implement an activity for `ACTION_SEND` and a MIME type of `text/plain`:

```
<activity android:name="URLTagger" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```